# Como pasar datos en variables a través de formulario en ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tengo una pequeña duda anteriormente en `C#` para pasar los datos los almacenábamos en una variable y lo enviamos de un formulario a otro y se visualizaba o usaba dependiendo la necesidad, pero ahora en `ASP CORE` tengo el siguiente escenario el cual a través de la variable `ítem` muestro el nombre de un paciente "X" como se ve en el código que describo a continuación, posterior a esto tengo 2 botones los cuales me llevan a otras áreas, es posible realizar lo mismo que hacia en `C#`?.

Una pequeña actualización en la cual a través del `asp-route-pac` envió por la url el nombre del paciente, pero ahora en el otro formulario como puedo ese valor que envié por la url ponerlo en una variable y mostrarlo en un input, como se ve en la imagen.

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.List)
        {
            var image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(item.PAC_IMAGEN, 0, item.PAC_IMAGEN.Length);
            var paciente = item.PAC_APELLIDO+' '+item.PAC_NOMBRE;
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header ">
                        <a asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                            <img class='imageUsers' src="@image" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAC_NOMBRE)</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAC_APELLIDO)</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="justify-content-center">
                            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                                <a class="col btn btn-success m-2" style="margin-top: 5px" asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                                    Detalle.
                                </a>
                                <a class="col btn btn-success m-2" style="margin-top: 5px"  asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-route-pac="@paciente" asp-area="Presupuesto" asp-page="/Account/Reg_Presup">
                                    Presup.
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-1">
                                    <a class="col btn btn-success m-2"; asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                                        Historia Clinica.
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: y probaste hacerlo?

Comment: Realmente no, porque no tengo la menor idea lo único que hice fue guardar los datos en una variable pero como lo puedo pasar a través de la url o como variable?, me puedes dar una ayuda por favor

Comment: @ramiro-barone actualice la pregunta como pueda hacer lo que estoy preguntando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model.List)
    {
        var image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(item.PAC_IMAGEN, 0, item.PAC_IMAGEN.Length);
        var paciente = item.PAC_APELLIDO+' '+item.PAC_NOMBRE;
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header ">
                    <a asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                        <img class='imageUsers' src="@image" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAC_NOMBRE)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PAC_APELLIDO)</p>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="justify-content-center">
                        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                            <a class="col btn btn-success m-2" style="margin-top: 5px" asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                                Detalle.
                            </a>
                            <a class="col btn btn-success m-2" style="margin-top: 5px"  asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-route-pac="@paciente" asp-area="Presupuesto" asp-page="/Account/Reg_Presup">
                                Presup.
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-1">
                                <a class="col btn btn-success m-2"; asp-route-id="@item.PAC_ID" asp-area="Paciente" asp-page="/Account/Detalle">
                                    Historia Clinica.
                                </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Adjunto código con una modificación `asp-route-pac="@paciente"` la cual me permite pasar a través de la url el nombre del paciente y posteriormente lo único que hago en la pagina donde deseo obtener el nombre es recoger ese valor con el siguiente código.

```
@page
@model Reg_PresupModel
@{
    var pacpre = Request.Query["pac"];
}
```